# When using wrapper for async function for catching error, where to use special clean up function?

Tags: node.js, express

```
module.exports=fn=>{
    return (req,res,next)=>{
        fn(req,res,next).catch(next);
    }
}


func=catchAsync(async (req,res,next)=>{
    
   conn=new Connection();
   task= await someFunc()
   conn.release()
});
```

So, I use this to wrap async function for errors. But where should I do clean up task when there are some error?

Comment: Do you really have `*` characters littered throughout your code?

Comment: I am not used to making questions here. When I just pasted the code here, it gave error. I just thought to make it italic. Don't know why the astreik came here.

Comment: Just type `\`\`\``, press `Enter`, paste your code, press `Enter` and type `\`\`\``. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting